# jQuery - Get CSS Selector In Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I want to get the selector for an element exactly the same with which is written in the stylesheet.

For example, I have a stylesheet which is containing a style of an `input` field like so:

```
#parent .children input {
    property: value;
}

input {
   property: value;
}

.input_field {
   property: value;
}
```

and the html is as the following example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="children">
      <input class="input_field" type="text" name="input_field" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

When that `input` field is clicked, I want to get all of its selector from the stylesheet using jquery:

```
$("input").on("click", function(){
    // get my selectors from stylesheet
});
```

How can it be done?

Comment: why do you need that

Comment: explain your problem, there might be other ways of doing that ?

Comment: The naïve way would be to iterate through the cssRules of every document stylesheet and test every selector against the element. If your CSS rules will not change, do this on page load rather than on click. But yes, it's not clear why exactly you need a list of selectors from a stylesheet that match an element.

Comment: `$('input, * input')` ????

Comment: Smells like an X/Y problem.

Comment: I want to make a stylesheet editor. I need to compare the same selector. I know I can hard code it, but it need to be done dynamically, without first knowing how the selectors is written inside the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Although even I wonder why do you need this, but lets not hang over there.

You need very simple `document` object to perform your task.

Essentially, `document.styleSheets` gives you all the stylesheets, attached to the web page.
Using this, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: I had checked it out before, but it looks like an overkill for me.

Comment: @SoursopTree A logical and actual object is overkill? Just wow. No matter what you use, library or otherwise, it'll use this very object. Only thing is logic you write to use in your system, which is all your work. But do enlighten me with any other solution which doesn't use this object